# Obtain smooth plot from a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a system of two partial differential equation with their boundary conditions that I solve with the function `NDSolve`. This is my code:

```
σ = 0.5;
τ = 2/3;
τ1 = 1;
y1 = -30;
y2 = 30;

eq1 = Sqrt[3]/2*D[int1[x, y], x] - 1/2*D[int1[x, y], y] - 
        D[int2[x, y], y] == 1/2*(int1[x, y] - int2[x, y]);

eq2 = Sqrt[3]/2*D[int2[x, y], x] + D[int1[x, y], y] + 
        1/2 D[int2[x, y], y] == 1/2*(int1[x, y] - int2[x, y]);

sol = NDSolve[
        {eq1, eq2, int1[τ1, y] == Exp[-((y)^2/(2*σ^2))], int2[0, y] == 0}, 
        {int1, int2}, {x, 0, τ1}, {y, y1, y2}];

int1[x_, y_] = int1[x, y] /. sol;

Plot3D[int1[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, τ1}, {y, y1, y2}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
Plot[int1[0, y], {y, -1, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

The problem is that I sometimes obtain a smooth function changing my parameters and sometimes I do not, depending also on `y1` and `y2`. Is there a method to increase the smoothness of the function obtained by `NDSolve`? Why does the solution seem to change when I change `y1` and `y2` leaving the other parameters unchanged?

P.S. The Gaussian function as boundary condition had to be a `DiracDelta` but Mathematica was not able to evaluate the solution with that condition.

This is an example of a smooth curve that i got:
[image]

using:

```
σ = 0.5;
τ = 2/3;
τ1 = 0.5;
y1 = -30;
y2 = 30;
```

This is an example of another curve that i got:
[image]

```
σ = 0.1;
τ = 2/3;
τ1 = 0.5;
y1 = -30;
y2 = 30;
```

If you reduce σ a little bit you obtain a not "smooth" function.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you consider *"smooth"* and not so?

Comment: With smooth i mean a curve that doesn't have point in which the derivative is not continuous

Comment: An example please, not a definition

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks for the pics; could you also include the parameter values that led to them, so people can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added also the parameter with that i obtain the two different kind of plot.